# Using an typescript interface to represent structured data from Firebase?

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

To pass data between my Angular application and RealTimeDb,  I like to create an interface that I can cast the objects returned by realtime DB into a specific interface, to help with consistency and code completion etc.

When it comes to reading objects 'map-like' structures, like this,

```
 family: {
    name: Morgan,       
    children: {
        Jack : 22
        Tara : 27
    }
 }
```

I tried using an interface with a map type, such as

```
     interface Family {
        name: string;
        children: Map<string, number>
     }
```

And I can read data from the db into a object that seems to *sort of* conform to the interface with a statement `

```
 let data = ref.get()
 let family = <Family>(await data).val();
```

But `family.children` isn't actually map, (and so has no .get() function), its an object, and, and also I can't change the map and write the whole thing back to the database.
The .children are just left off entirely if I use set.

Wondering how I can represent firebase data using an interface that will bother read and write structured data?

Answer (score 0):

> But family.children isn't actually map, (and so has no .get() function), **its an object**

You are right, it is an object. So you need a better type to represent `children`.

I would recommend [`Record<string, number>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) instead.

If you desire a `Map`, you will need to create a map and insert all the key/values into it from children.